# Error in create table with partitions in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I am getting error:
Error Code: 1064. Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed

What is the reason? and How do I get rid of this error?

```
    CREATE TABLE TB_TEST_HIST(
    TEST_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    START_TIME DATETIME,
    END_TIME DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(TEST_ID)
    )ENGINE=INNODB PARTITION BY RANGE (START_TIME) (
    PARTITION TEST_HIST_P0 VALUES LESS THAN  
    (ADDTIME(DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE()) ,'%Y-%m-%d %00:00:00'), '1 
    0:0:0.000000')),
    PARTITION TEST_HIST_P1 VALUES LESS THAN ( 
    ADDTIME(DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE()) ,'%Y-%m-%d %00:00:00'), '2   
    0:0:0.000000'))
    );
```

Comment: Try using `now()` instead of `sysdate()`.

Comment: I tried it with now(), but no difference in error.